# Mostrar 2 modal con diferentes botones

Tags: php, html, modal

Buen dia

Tengo el siguiente codigo y tengo 2 botones mediante los cuales mando a llamar 2 modals diferentes con el primero identificado con id=#editChildresn si me muestra el modal sin problemas, pero al presionar el segundo identificado con id=#folioChildresn no me muestra el segundo formulario solo se queda la pantalla sombreada.

A continuacion anexo imagen de como se queda la pantalla y el codigo que estoy utilizando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="embar" id="employee_data">
        <thead>
            <tr align=center>
                <th># Rampa</th>
                <th># Trailer</th>
                <th>Destino</th>
                <th>Material de descarga</th>
                <th>Fecha Programada</th>
                <th>Liberacion</th>
                <th scope="col">Acción</th>   
                <th>Estatus</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){
                
                $id=$row['id_emb'];
                ?>
                
                <tr>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['rampa']?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['trailer'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['plant_code'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['type_material'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['prog_date'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['liberado'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editChildresn<?php echo $row['id_emb']; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#folioChildresn<?php echo $row['id_emb']; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    
                    <?php 
                    
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
                    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
                    $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['prog_date']);
                    $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');
                    
                    // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
                    
                    if ($dias <0) {
                    echo '<td align=center ><font color="#FF0000">' . $dias . ' de atraso</font></td>';
                }
                elseif ($dias ==0){
                    echo '<td align=center ><font color="#FF8C00">En proceso</font></td>';
                }
                if($dias >=1) {
                    echo '<td align=center ><Font color="#3CB371"> En tiempo </FONT></td>';
                }
                
                echo "</tr>"; ?>
                
                <!--Ventana Modal para Actualizar--->
                <?php  include('ModalEditar.php'); ?>

                <!--Ventana Modal para registrar folio de salida--->
                <?php  include('ModalLiber.php'); ?>
                
                <?php} ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<!--ventana para Liberar--->
<div class="modal fade" id="folioChildresn<?= $row['id_emb']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #563d7c !important;">
        <h6 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff; text-align: center;">
            Folio de liberacion
        </h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>


      <form method="POST" action="recib_lib.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_emb" value="<?= $row['id_emb']?>">

            <div class="modal-body" id="cont_modal">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Folio de liberacion:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="lib" value="<?php echo $row['liberado']; ?>" required='true' autofocus>
                </div><br>

            <div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
            </div>
       </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---fin ventana Liberar --->
```

Ya probe con poner los botones en `<td>` separados y de igual manera me deja la pantalla sombreada ya intente incluso con un boton de `danger` y de igual manera no hace nada pero si al segundo boton mando a llamar al mismo modal que el primero si lo abre.

Me podrian orientar

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que no puedo ver el código de los modal, te invito a que verifiques el **ID** de cada uno comprobando que estén bien escritos tanto en uno como en el otro modal, luego verifica con el **inspector de elementos** del navegador que se creen todos los modal y que los **IDs** correspondan a los indicados en **data-target**.

Si continuas con el problema comparte el código de los modal o por lo menos una foto de cada uno, eso nos ayudará a guiarte mejor.

Saludos.

Comment: Listo ya lo añadi y ya revise los id

Comment: Puedes subir el proyecto a alguna web para revisarlo mejor y ayudarte, así visualmente no puedo encontrar el error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajhm47az6241m4e/Control%20de%20rampas.rar?dl=0

De ahi puedes descargar el proyecto

Comment: El archivo index0 es el que estoy utilizando para hacer pruebas antes de pasarlo al archivo principal

Comment: Acabo de descubrir que si borro la linea de codigo ```<?php  include('ModalEditar.php'); ?>``` me funciona el modal que no me abre pero si dejo las dos lineas de codigo donde incluyo los modal solo abre el ```modaleditar.php```, pero sigo sin saber por que